# Ruby (Errno::EACCES) on File.delete - previous solution doesn't work

Tags: ruby, chmod, delete-file

I am having exactly the same issue as the poster of this question : [Ruby (Errno::EACCES) on File.delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537403/ruby-errnoeacces-on-file-delete).  Unlike him, the change provided in the solution for him does not work for me.

Here is my code, it is a compression algorithm where I want to delete the original file :

```
uncompressed_file = File.new(Rails.root + filepath)
compressed_file = File.new(Rails.root + "#{filepath[0..filepath.size - 1]}.gz", "w+b")
file_writer = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(compressed_file)

buf = ""
File.open(uncompressed_file, "rb") do | uncompressed |
  while uncompressed.read(4096, buf)
    file_writer << buf
  end
  file_writer.close
end    

begin      
  files_changed_by_chmod = File.chmod(0777, uncompressed_file)
rescue
  puts "Something happened"
end    
puts "Number of files changed by CHMOD : " + files_changed_by_chmod.to_s
File.delete(uncompressed_file)
File.rename(Rails.root + "#{filepath[0..filepath.size - 1]}.gz", Rails.root + filepath)
```

You'll notice there are a couple `puts` in there to confirm what is happening with the chmod.  The output is this :

`Number of files changed by CHMOD : 1`

and there is no `Something happened`.  Therefore there is no error generated by running the chmod, and chmod indeed modifies one file (presumably, the `uncompressed_file`.)  However, I still get the Errno::EACCESS error on the delete line.

Why can't I delete the files?!  It's driving me up the wall.  I'm running Windows 8 and ruby 1.9.3.

**EDIT:** The first answer below solves the issue of not being able to delete the files; however, it invalidates the job my code is trying to do (i.e, when my files are run through the compression algorithm supplied in the solution and then my other algorithms, the file comes back corrupted).  Yes, I did also try to emulate the coding style here in my inflation method, but that didn't help.  Here is the rest of the code that performs the encryption, decryption, and decompression of my files :

```
def inflate_attachment(filepath)
    compressed_file = File.new(Rails.root + filepath)

    File.open(compressed_file, "rb") do | compressed |
      File.open(Rails.root + "#{filepath[0..filepath.size - 7]}_FULL.enc", 'w+b') do | decompressed |
        gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(compressed)
        result = gz.read
        decompressed.write(result)
        gz.close
      end
    end
  end

def encrypt_attachment(filepath, cipher)
    unencrypted_file = File.new(Rails.root + filepath)     
    encrypted_file = File.new(Rails.root + "#{filepath[0..filepath.size - 1]}.enc", "w")

    buf = ""
    File.open(encrypted_file, "wb") do |outf|
      File.open(unencrypted_file, "rb") do |inf|
        while inf.read(4096, buf)
          outf << cipher.update(buf)
        end
        outf << cipher.final
      end
    end
  end

def decrypt_attachment(filepath, key, iv)
    cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new(ENCRYPTION_TYPE)
    cipher.decrypt
    cipher.key = key
    cipher.iv = iv

    encrypted_file = File.new(Rails.root + filepath)  
    decrypted_file = File.new(Rails.root + "#{filepath[0..filepath.size - 5]}.dec", "w")

    buf = ""
    File.open(decrypted_file, "wb") do |outf|
      File.open(encrypted_file, "rb") do |inf|
        while inf.read(4096, buf)
          outf << cipher.update(buf)
        end
        outf << cipher.final
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that might have something to do that you haven't properly closed the files. I took the liberty to rewrite your code, without the chmod stuff (which I don't think is necessary)

```
filename = <your sourcefilename goes here>
filename_gz = filename + ".gz"

filepath = Rails.root + filename
filepath_gz = Rails.root + filename_gz

# gzip the file
buffer = ""
File.open(filepath) do |file|
  Zlib::GzipWriter.open(filepath_gz) do |gz|
    while file.read(4096, buffer)
      gz << buffer
    end
  end
end

# moves the filepath_gz to filepath (overwriting the original file in the process!)
FileUtils.mv(filepath_gz, filepath)
```

As you can see I've used File.open(path) and passed a block. This has the effect that the files will be closed automatically when the block exits.
I've also changed the delete/rename code to simply move the gziped file to the original path, which has the same effect.

However, I strongly advice you to keep a backup of your original file.

Comment: Hi Sascha, thanks a lot for this response.  It looks very elegant and the code indeed allows me to delete the original file -- however, it causes the compressed file to lose integrity (after I then encrypt it, decrypt it, and decompress it again).  I will update the original question with the rest of the code.

Comment: Glad I could help at least with the file delete issue.

Comment: Turns out, something else in my code completely was causing the problem of the integrity collapse.  It was actually this fix for the deleting issue that exposed that other issue (it had to do with pathing).  Thanks again Sascha.